# Randomly getting error service unavailable for Google Assistant PushToTalk with Raspberry PI b model. How to fix error or how to handle this error

Tags: raspberry-pi, google-assistant-sdk

I have implemented Google Assistant in RaspBerry PI B model with the latest OS. I have followed [google's instructions from here](https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/tree/master/google-assistant-sdk/googlesamples/assistant/grpc).

Audio sample testing working fine.

Many times it is working.

```
.asoundrc file
   pcm.!default{ 
   type asym
   playback.pcm{type plug slave.pcm "hw:0"}
   capture.pcm{type plug slave.pcm "hw:1"}
}

ctl.!default{
   type hw
   card 0
}
```

Error :-

```
INFO:root:Recording audio request.
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main"__main__", mod_spec)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_codeexec(code, run_globals)
      File "/home/pi/teamaker/grpc/pushtotalk_back.py", line 337, in <module>main()
      File "/home/pi/teamaker/grpc/env_local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/click/core.py", line 722, in __call__return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/pi/teamaker/grpc/env_local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/click/core.py", line 697, in main\ rv = self.invoke(ctx)
      File "/home/pi/teamaker/grpc/env_local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/click/core.py", line 895, in invoke
        return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
      File "/home/pi/teamaker/grpc/env_local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/click/core.py", line 535, in invoke
        return callback(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/pi/teamaker/grpc/pushtotalk_back.py", line 326, in main
        continue_conversation = assistant.converse()
      File "/home/pi/teamaker/grpc/env_local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tenacity/__init__.py", line 87, in wrapped_f
        return r.call(f, *args, **kw)
      File "/home/pi/teamaker/grpc/env_local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tenacity/__init__.py", line 235, in call
        do = self.iter(result=result, exc_info=exc_info)
      File "/home/pi/teamaker/grpc/env_local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tenacity/__init__.py", line 194, in iter
        return fut.result()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 398, in result
        return self.__get_result()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 357, in __get_result
        raise self._exception
      File "/home/pi/teamaker/grpc/env_local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tenacity/__init__.py", line 238, in call
        result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/pi/teamaker/grpc/pushtotalk_back.py", line 145, in converse
        self.conversation_stream.stop_playback()
      File "/home/pi/teamaker/grpc/audio_helpers.py", line 288, in stop_playback
        self._source.stop()
      File "/home/pi/teamaker/grpc/audio_helpers.py", line 222, in stop
        self._audio_stream.stop()
      File "/home/pi/teamaker/grpc/env_local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sounddevice.py", line 1235, in stop
        _check(err, 'Error stopping stream')
      File "/home/pi/teamaker/grpc/env_local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sounddevice.py", line 2671, in _check
        raise PortAudioError(msg)
sounddevice.PortAudioError: Error stopping stream: Unanticipated host API 0 error -77: 'File descriptor in bad state'
```